# Problema con suplantación de identidad en cuentas de correo

Tags: email, centos

Tengo un servidor postfix en Centos 7, el problema es que hace poco les empezó a llegar a algunas cuentas un mensaje de spam que luce como si ellos mismos se lo mandaran. Lo pude bloquear con **spamassassin** pero se da el problema que el rebote que hace el spamassassin les cae a ellos mismos. ¿Alguna idea de como solucionar este problema?

El mensaje es este:

> Dear manuel.martinez,
>
> We are looking for employees working remotely.
>
> My name is Olen, I am the personnel manager of a large International company.
>   Most of the work you can do from home, that is, at a distance.
>   Salary is $2300-$5900.
>
> If you are interested in this offer, please visit Our Site
>
> Good day!

He revisado los encabezados y las ips de origen me salen países asiáticos.

Answer (score 0):

En estos casos de phising, lo mas aconsejable es que crees un registro SPF, y por supuesto, tambien lo utilices como medida antispam en el correo de entrada.

Comment: nosotros contamos con un registro SPF v=spf1 mx a ip4:67.205.151.88/20 -all  no se si debamos agregar algo más para mejorarlo

Comment: Obviamente, debe estar reducido a los rangos que pueden mandar correos, pero si el correo procede del exterior, no hay mucho más que puedas hacer. Y por supuesto, asegurate que no parte de algún equipo infectado en tu LAN. De todas formas, si se están utilizando tus direcciones para falsear envíos, es porque en algún momento han capturado alguna de tus cuentas, pero bueno, suelen rotar y no utilizan las mismas durante mucho tiempo.